# Why my bestFirst method never terminates?

Tags: java

The method bestFirst computes the path for a given goal state, and the given initial value "MI"(using the MIU system). When i am trying to call bestFirst method in the main class, the method never terminates. For example if you try with input goal state "MUUUIIIII", the BFS (breadthFirstSearch) outputs should be "Cannot find the goal String MUUUIIIII", and the bestFirst should output the answer.

Can anyone spot why is that?
Thank you

main class code:

```
public class main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    MIU miu = new MIU();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = "";
    ArrayList<String> p = new ArrayList<String>();


    System.out.println("\n" +"What is your goal string?");
    String goalStr = sc.nextLine();

    System.out.println("BFS:");

    try
    {
        ArrayList<String> curPath = miu.breadthFirstSearch(goalStr);
        for (int i=0; i<curPath.size(); i++)
        {
            System.out.print(curPath.get(i) + ", ");
        }

    } catch (NullPointerException E)
    {
        System.out.println("Cannot find the goal String " + goalStr);
    }


    System.out.println("\n" + "\n" + "Best First: ");
    try
    {

        ArrayList<String> path = miu.bestFirst(goalStr);

        for (int i=0; i<path.size(); i++)
        {
            System.out.print(path.get(i) + ", ");
        }

    } catch (NullPointerException E)
    {
        System.out.println("Cannot find the goal String " + goalStr);
    }

    System.out.println("\n" + "\n" + "A*: ");
    try
    {
        ArrayList<String> path = miu.AStar(goalStr);
        for (int i=0; i<path.size(); i++)
        {
            System.out.print(path.get(i) + ", ");
        }

    } catch (NullPointerException E)
    {
        System.out.println("Cannot find the goal String " + goalStr);
    }

}
```

}

MIU class code:

```
public class MIU {

public  ArrayList<String> nextStates = new ArrayList<String>();
public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> paths = new ArrayList<>();

public void rule1(String s)
{
    String n= "";
    if (s.charAt(s.length() - 1) == 'I')
    {
        n = s+'U';
        if(!nextStates.contains(n))
            nextStates.add(n);
    }
}

public void rule2(String s)
{
    String n = "";
    if(s.charAt(0) == 'M')
    {
        n = s.substring(0, 1) + s.substring(1, s.length()) + s.substring(1, s.length());
        if(!nextStates.contains(n)) nextStates.add(n);
    }
}

public void rule3(String s)
{
    String n= "";
    if(s.contains("III"))
    {
        for (int i=0; i<s.length()-2; i++)
        {
            if (s.charAt(i) == 'I' && s.charAt(i+1) == 'I' && s.charAt(i+2) == 'I')
            {
                n = s.substring(0, i) + 'U' + s.substring(i+3, s.length());
                if(!nextStates.contains(n)) nextStates.add(n);
            }
        }
    }
}

public void rule4(String s)
{
    String n= "";
    if(s.contains("UU"))
    {
        for (int i=0; i<s.length()-2; i++) {
            if (s.charAt(i) == 'U' && s.charAt(i + 1) == 'U') {

                n = s.substring(0, i) + s.substring(i + 2, s.length());
                if(!nextStates.contains(n)) nextStates.add(n);
            }
        }
    }
}

public ArrayList<String> next_States(String s)
{
    rule1(s);
    rule2(s);
    rule3(s);
    rule4(s);
    return nextStates;
}



public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> extendPath(ArrayList<String> p)
{
    nextStates.clear();
    String last = p.get(p.size()-1);
    next_States(last);

    for (int i=0; i<nextStates.size(); i++)
    {
        ArrayList<String> temp_states = new ArrayList<>();
        temp_states.addAll(p);
        temp_states.add(nextStates.get(i));

        paths.add(temp_states);
    }

    return paths;
}


public ArrayList<String> breadthFirstSearch (String goalString)
{
    nextStates.clear();
    //agenda is a list of paths
    //path is a list of states
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> agenda = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> mi = new ArrayList<>();
    mi.add("MI");
    agenda.add(mi);
    ArrayList<String> currentPath = agenda.get(0);

    int extendPathCounter = 0;
    int lim = 300;
    while (lim >= extendPathCounter)
    {

        if (currentPath.get(currentPath.size()-1).equals(goalString))
        {
            System.out.println("Lenght of path = " + currentPath.size());
            System.out.println("Number of calls of extendPath = " + extendPathCounter);
            System.out.println("Size of agenda = " + agenda.size());
            return currentPath;
        }

        else {
            paths.clear();
            extendPath(currentPath);
            extendPathCounter++;
            for (int i=0; i<paths.size(); i++)
            {
                agenda.add(paths.get(i));
            }
            agenda.remove(0);
            currentPath = agenda.get(0);
        }
    }
    return null; // TODO should return an empty list
}



public int estimateSteps(String currentString, String goalString)
{
    if (currentString.equals(goalString)) return 0;
    else return 1;
}

public ArrayList<String> bestFirst(String goalString)
{
    nextStates.clear();
    //agenda is a list of paths
    //path is a list of states
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> agenda = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> mi = new ArrayList<>();
    mi.add("MI");
    agenda.add(mi);
    ArrayList<String> currentPath;

    int extendPathCounter = 0;
    while (agenda.size()!=0)
    {
        currentPath = agenda.get(0);
        int index = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<agenda.size(); i++)
        {
            if(estimateSteps(goalString, currentPath.get(currentPath.size()-1)) > estimateSteps(goalString, agenda.get(i).get(agenda.get(i).size()-1)))
            {
                currentPath = agenda.get(i);
                index = i;
            }
        }
        agenda.remove(index); //remove the one that is the current path
        if (currentPath.get(currentPath.size()-1).equals(goalString))
        {
            System.out.println("Lenght of path = " + currentPath.size());
            System.out.println("Number of calls of extendPath = " + extendPathCounter);
            System.out.println("Size of agenda = " + agenda.size());
            return currentPath;
        }
        else
        {
            paths.clear();
            extendPath(currentPath);
            extendPathCounter++;
            for (int i=0; i<paths.size(); i++)
            {
                agenda.add(paths.get(i));
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public ArrayList<String> AStar(String goalString)
{
    nextStates.clear();
    //agenda is a list of paths
    //path is a list of states
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> agenda = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> mi = new ArrayList<>();
    mi.add("MI");
    agenda.add(mi);
    ArrayList<String> currentPath;

    int extendPathCounter = 0;
    while (agenda.size()!=0)
    {
        int heuristics;
        int pathLen;
        int sum;
        currentPath = agenda.get(0);
        int index = 0;
        heuristics = estimateSteps(goalString, currentPath.get(currentPath.size()-1));
        pathLen = currentPath.size();
        sum = heuristics + pathLen;

        for (int i= 0; i<agenda.size(); i++)
        {
            int h = estimateSteps(goalString, agenda.get(i).get(agenda.get(i).size()-1));
            int pl = agenda.get(i).size();
            int s = h+pl;
            if(s<sum)
            {
                currentPath = agenda.get(i);
                index = i;
            }
        }

        agenda.remove(index);
        if (currentPath.get(currentPath.size()-1).equals(goalString))
        {
            System.out.println("Lenght of path = " + currentPath.size());
            System.out.println("Number of calls of extendPath = " + extendPathCounter);
            System.out.println("Size of agenda = " + agenda.size());
            return currentPath;
        }
        else
        {
            paths.clear();
            extendPath(currentPath);
            extendPathCounter++;
            for (int i=0; i<paths.size(); i++)
            {
                agenda.add(paths.get(i));
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: `catch (NullPointerException E)` should not be in your code. NPE is an unchecked exception, meaning you shouldn't catch it.

Comment: Your code is adding more to the agenda `ArrayList` than it is removing. I printed the size of agenda in the while loop and it just keeps increasing. Also since you are removing at a given index from an `ArrayList`, you should use a `LinkedList` instead of an `ArrayList`

Comment: Use your debugger to find out why.